Find $ \inf \sum\limits_{i=1}^r \left| a+ \sqrt{\alpha_i} \right|^p,$ where, $\sum\limits_{i=1}^r \alpha_i = c,$ for some $c\geq 0.$
Let $c \geq 0$ and consider the set $E= \left\{ (\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \ldots, \alpha_r) \in \mathbb{C}^r : \sum\limits_{i=1}^r \alpha_i = c \right\}.$ Then for any $a> 0$ and $p>1$ find $$\inf\limits_{(\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \ldots, \alpha_r) \in E} \sum\limits_{i=1}^r \left| a+ \sqrt{\alpha_i} \right|^p.$$
Nb: In my guess, for $(c,0,0,0,\ldots,0)$ kind of tuple infimum will attain. Atleast can someone try it for real case.

First I tried for real case and for $p=1.$ I have proved that for $(c,0,0,0,\ldots,0)$ kind of tuple infimum will attain for this case. But for $p> 1$ case I could not able to prove it. At least if somebody can prove it for the real case i.e. when $\alpha_i \in \mathbb{R},$ I can get some idea.

For $\alpha_i$ real the solution depends on $p$. In fact for $p=1$ the solution is the one you said, but for $p\to \infty$ the solution is $\alpha_i = c/r$

Could you please give me the proof for p>1 case.
